ArcGIS Pro Orthomosaic Workspace empty
I am attempting to process drone imagery in ArcGIS Pro for the first time following this ESRI tutorial. However, after I go through the 'Create an ortho mapping workspace' steps and click the 'Finish' button, nothing seems to happen in ArcGIS Pro. Looking in my ArcGIS project folder reveals that a new 'OrthoMapping' folder has been created with a '.eomw' folder inside. When I manually connect this folder using Imagery > New Workspace > Add Workspace, it does add to my project but there is nothing inside. I assume that there should be 'source data' and 'flight data' imported from the drone images uploaded but when I right click these in the contents, the 'Turn Layers on' and 'Turn Layers Off' buttons are greyed out suggesting that there is no data to turn on or off.
The images show up correctly on the 'Image Collection' tab while creating a new Ortho Mapping Workspace and the spatial reference and camera model are correctly read. I know the imagery has good data because I uploaded and processed it through DroneDeploy with no issue. Imagery is from a DJI Mavic Pro 2.
Closing and reopening ArcGIS did not fix the issue. I turned on Enable Task History and looked at the Log tab of the Diagnostic Monitor after trying again. This error message showed up but searching online for 'arcgis pro error -2147024893' came up with nothing.
Why is my Ortho Mapping Workspace not being properly created in ArcGIS Pro?


The issue had something to do with the existing project I was trying to create the Ortho Mapping Workspace in. When I tried again in a new, empty project, everything worked as expected. I'm not sure what the issue with the existing project was but if you run into a similar issue, try creating a new, empty project and creating the new Ortho Mapping Workspace there.
